# Laravel 5.1 Token Mismatch on Login form POST

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm getting the following error `TokenMismatchException in compiled.php line 2930:`

The code is running on a `Red Hat server` with `php 5.6` i have also tested this on a `Ubuntu server` running `php 5.5.9` it worked perfectly fine. It also runs perfectly locally.

It seems to create 2 session files in `storage/framework/sessions` on the original `GET` request which means when the form is sent via `POST` the session is then different.

I have checked for

- Redirects
- Date/Timezone issue across the server
- Config issues within `session.php` and `app.php`

The strangest thing is why there is 2 session files being generated on the `GET` request.

As soon as you hit the login button you hit the `csrf` middleware saying the tokens don't match.

I am using the HTML generator for forms which means the `_token` is being set so it doesn't need to happen manually.

**Form code**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'Auth\AuthController@login']) !!}

<div class="panel">

    <div class="panel-title">
        Login
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="grid">

            <div class="grid-2-4 grid-prepend-1-4 grid-append-1-4">

                @include('shared._errors')

                <div class="field">
                    {!! Form::label('username', 'Employee username') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('username') !!}
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    {!! Form::label('password', 'Password') !!}
                    {!! Form::password('password') !!}
                </div>

                <div class="actions">
                    {!! Form::submit('Login', ['class' => 'button large']) !!}
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Session config**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 45,

    'expire_on_close' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => 'geeksquad_form_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => '.'.config('app.domain'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => false,

];
```

If there is anything else that would be helpful let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of the issue.

It was to do with this line in the `session.php` config file.

`'domain' => '.'.config('app.domain')`

This line is getting the domain from the `config.php` file which in turn gets it from the `.env` file.

Ubuntu and Locally in Homestead which is also Ubuntu this works flawlessly.

However on Red Hat this does not work at all. Altering the line to be `'domain' => '.'.env('APP_DOMAIN')` and voilà all is right with the world and the TokenMissmatch has gone.

Comment: You have to use csrf_token, inside the form, to prevent the error. csrf_token gives you an extra security from various attacks.

Comment: I do believe you didn't read the whole question. The form code posted is a `blade` template and is using the `HTML/Form` generated that was removed from `Laravel 5` this auto generates the `_token' when you use `Form::open`

I also posted the answer.

Comment: I personally use laravel 5, and gone through the issue before, thats why i gave you the solution. Laravel generates the csrf_token, for sure, but you have to include it in form, so that when you post the data, laravel checks the csrf_token to ensure that it is from the right source and not not manipulated through other sources. Neways, other than this, i have no other solution.

Comment: Again i posted the answer to my own question. Also the way the form is built using the form generator it is automatically added to the page so there is no need to add it manually.

Comment: I Agree with you Matt